# What is the correct way to write a response to both the client and to console on the server?

Tags: java, printwriter, system.out

I am trying to determine the correct way to write an httpstatus to both the client and also echo print on the server.  Here is my code.  I'm using a servlet.  Thanks for replies.

```
response.setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
PrintWriter printWriter = response.getWriter();
try {
    printWriter.println(httpStatus);    //message to the client
    System.out.println(httpStatus);     //message to the server
} finally {
     printWriter.close();
}
```

Comment: Is there any problem with the above code?

Comment: that is what i'm trying to discover...is the above code correct way to notify both the client and server console.

Comment: I think what you are doing is right :)

Answer (score 0):

set response header with status, as below:

response.setStatus(httpStatus);

for more info, @see [http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#setStatus(int)](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#setStatus%28int%29)